# Rewrite logical combination expression

Tags: vhdl

Have a an `array` of type `std_logic_vector` which holds some status flags which I have to combine(OR) into one single flag of type `std_logic`.

Is there a more elegant and effective way than doing it by hand

```
flag <= x(0)(1) OR x(1)(1) OR x(2)(1) OR x(3)(1) OR x(4)(1) OR x(5)(1) OR 
        x(6)(1) OR x(7)(1) OR x(8)(1) OR x(9)(1) OR x(10)(1) OR x(11)(1) OR
        x(12)(1) OR x(13)(1) OR x(14)(1);
```

Can this be achieved using some kind of `generate` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop.

```
flag := false;
for i in 0 to x'high loop
  flag := flag or x(i)(1);
end loop;
```

If you insist on having flag be a signal, use a function which uses a loop. In fact, always use this function, but also turn flag into a variable.

```
function or_reduce_index(array : t_flag_array_type,
                         flag_index : natural) return std_logic is
  variable result : std_logic;
begin
  result := false;
  for i in 0 to array'high loop
    result := result or array(i)(flag_index);
  end loop;
  return result;
end;

flag := or_reduce_index(x, 1); -- somewhere else
```

Flag should probably also be a boolean.